# How to prevent file name "index.html?replytocom=xxx" in wget

Tags: wget

Im trying to remove lots of strange file name, like `index.html?replytocom=653`, `index.html?replytocom=667`, etc.

Im using below code:

```
wget -k -m -r -q -R gif,png,jpg,jpeg,GIF,PNG,JPG,JPEG,?,= -t 1 http://www.website.com/
```

and tried also

```
wget -k -m -r -q -R gif,png,jpg,jpeg,GIF,PNG,JPG,JPEG,?,=,replytocom -t 1 http://www.website.com/
```

but no luck..

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it's not possible to use `rejlist`, because the  [documentation for wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html) says:

> Note, too, that query strings (strings at the end of a URL beginning with a question mark (`?`) are not included as part of the filename for accept/reject rules, even though these will actually contribute to the name chosen for the local file. It is expected that a future version of Wget will provide an option to allow matching against query strings.

Therefore you need to use `--reject-regex` parameter instead.

```
wget --reject-regex '(.*)\?(.*)' http://example.com
```

Beware that it seems you can use `--reject-regex` only once per `wget` call.  That is, you have to use `|` in a single regex if you want to select on several regex :

```
wget --reject-regex 'expr1|expr2|…' http://example.com
```

---

So answering you question, I'm guessing the solution would be something like:

```
wget --reject-regex '(.*)replytocom(.*)' (...)
```